# c Can you use variables from other files without using include?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am reading the code of the ffmpeg project.In the fftools/ffmpeg.c file of this project, there is a piece of code on line 519:

```c
519         if (do_benchmark) {
520             int maxrss = getmaxrss() / 1024;
521             av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "bench: maxrss=%ikB\n", maxrss);
522         }
```

I use gdb to find the definition location of the do_benchmark variable:

```sh
(gdb) info variables do_benchmark
All variables matching regular expression "do_benchmark":

File fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c:
159:    int do_benchmark;
160:    int do_benchmark_all;
```

However, I cannot find a statement like include fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c in the fftools/ffmpeg.c file.I use find + grep to no avail.

```sh
$ find . -type f | xargs grep 'ffmpeg_opt'
grep: ./.git/objects/pack/pack-c2a6a6b1765b632f6fa88814ec92d3b0e4c11dad.pack：Match to binary file
grep: ./.git/index：Match to binary file
grep: ./ffmpeg：Match to binary file
./fftools/ffmpeg_opt.d:fftools/ffmpeg_opt.o: fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c fftools/ffmpeg.h config.h \
grep: ./fftools/ffmpeg_opt.o：Match to binary file
./fftools/Makefile:OBJS-ffmpeg                        += fftools/ffmpeg_opt.o fftools/ffmpeg_filter.o fftools/ffmpeg_hw.o
grep: ./ffmpeg_g：Match to binary file
```

I wanted to try a similar approach, but failed.

demo-01.c

```c
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void){
    fptintf(stdout, "demo: %d", demo);
    return 0;
}
```

demo-02.c

```c
int demo = 0;
```

```sh
$ gcc demo-01.c demo-02.c -o demo
demo-01.c: In the function ‘main’:
demo-01.c:4:33: Error: ‘demo’ is not declared (first use in this function)
    4 |     fprintf(stdout, "demo: %d", demo);
      |                                 ^~~~
demo-01.c:4:33: Note: Each undeclared identifier is only reported once in the function in which it appears.
```

why is that?

Comment: You must still *declare* the variable, even if it's defined in another translation unit.

Comment: You need to add `extern int demo;` in demo-01.c (also, you have an error in "fprintf")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you use variables from other files without using include?

Yes. If you *know* how the variable is declared inside a library or object file produced from another translation unit, you can make an `extern` declaration of the variable without including a header file - but that's not what's happening in this case.

> I cannot find a statement like include fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c in the fftools/ffmpeg.c

No, the variable is declared `extern` in `fftools/ffmpeg.h` like this:

```
extern int do_benchmark;
```

The actual definition is in `fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c` (as you've found out) and it will be compiled into the library. This makes it possible for `.c` files including `fftools/ffmpeg.h` to use the variable that is defined in `fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c` when linking with the library.